# Polynomial Long Division Using Polynom

Tags: polynom

I have been toiling around `polynom` package to typeset polynomial long division. The `polynom` package produces wonderful long division with step by step process. But I just have two problems. Let me tell you what I need exactly

Here is the output that I produced with `polynom` for `\polylongdiv{X^3+X^2-1}{X-1}`

[image]

But instead of spaces for the  missing x, I want to have 0x. Is it possible to do that? I checked the documentation and I couldn't find a way to do this.

You can read the documentation here: http://www.cs.brown.edu/system/software/latex/doc/polynom.pdf

I also realized that the polynomials aren't formatted inside the math environment. So is there anyway to format these equations inside math environment also? I tried putting `$` signs around `\polylongdiv{X^3+X^2-1}{X-1}`, but that didn't change anything. Equations inside math environment produces something like this

[image]

I am very new to latex. So please help me.

**Update: @polgab helped me solve the second question of producing math environment like output. I just need the solution for question 1 now which is I want to have 0x in the place of missing x instead of a space which is being produced by polynom.**

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I was just looking at [Multivariate polynomial long division using LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50404/multivariate-polynomial-long-division-using-latex/51043#51043), and was about to compose a question when I saw this.  Is this a duplicate that answers your question?

Comment: I edited your question and put the first image in there- the second image seemed to be the same?

Comment: @PeterGrill No mine is not a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50404/multivariate-polynomial-long-division-using-latex/51043#51043. I don't want to typeset multivariate polynomial long division. I just want to get help in modifying some basic settings of the polynom package. Thanks for taking your time to comment!

Comment: @cmhughes I just put the second image to show how the output from polynom is different from the output produced in the math environment. If you feel it is causing ambiguity, please feel free to remove it.

Comment: Have you try `\polylongdiv{x^3+x^2-1}{x-1}` (using `x` instead of `X`)?

Comment: @PolGab Thank you so much. It produces output similar to the math environment. You have solved one of my question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Changing the internal macros that are responsible for omitting zero terms you get what you want (but you have to specify the zero term in the input):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}
\makeatletter
\def\pld@CF@loop#1+{%
    \ifx\relax#1\else
        \begingroup
          \pld@AccuSetX11%
          \def\pld@frac{{}{}}\let\pld@symbols\@empty\let\pld@vars\@empty
          \pld@false
          #1%
          \let\pld@temp\@empty
          \pld@AccuIfOne{}{\pld@AccuGet\pld@temp
                            \edef\pld@temp{\noexpand\pld@R\pld@temp}}%
           \pld@if \pld@Extend\pld@temp{\expandafter\pld@F\pld@frac}\fi
           \expandafter\pld@CF@loop@\pld@symbols\relax\@empty
           \expandafter\pld@CF@loop@\pld@vars\relax\@empty
           \ifx\@empty\pld@temp
               \def\pld@temp{\pld@R11}%
           \fi
          \global\let\@gtempa\pld@temp
        \endgroup
        \ifx\@empty\@gtempa\else
            \pld@ExtendPoly\pld@tempoly\@gtempa
        \fi
        \expandafter\pld@CF@loop
    \fi}
\def\pld@CMAddToTempoly{%
    \pld@AccuGet\pld@temp\edef\pld@temp{\noexpand\pld@R\pld@temp}%
    \pld@CondenseMonomials\pld@false\pld@symbols
    \ifx\pld@symbols\@empty \else
        \pld@ExtendPoly\pld@temp\pld@symbols
    \fi
    \ifx\pld@temp\@empty \else
        \pld@if
            \expandafter\pld@IfSum\expandafter{\pld@temp}%
                {\expandafter\def\expandafter\pld@temp\expandafter
                    {\expandafter\pld@F\expandafter{\pld@temp}{}}}%
                {}%
        \fi
        \pld@ExtendPoly\pld@tempoly\pld@temp
        \pld@Extend\pld@tempoly{\pld@monom}%
    \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\polylongdiv{X^3+X^2+0X-1}{X-1}
\end{document}
```

[image]