# Teaking the polynomial long division sign in `polynom`

Tags: polynom

With

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{polynom}
\begin{document}
\[
    \polylongdiv{x^3+x^2-1}{x-1}
\]
\end{document}
```

we get something similar to the image in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63354/204820).

[image]

The line for the table in the long division looks like a closed parenthesis `)` and a line. The two appear disjoint. I would like to make them connected and, if possible, replace the parenthesis with a vertical straight line.

How to do this?

Note: In [the documentation](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/polynom/polynom.pdf) I saw `style=D`. It has straight lines, but the position of the numerator and denominator are swapped. I am writing for people that are used to the table written as in the default style. I would like to still have them like that, but with the separator looking nicer, in particular connected.

Comment: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/476518/579) shows long division in the form you are looking for, but "closed up".

Comment: Your question was answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648738/how-do-i-programmatically-typeset-polynomial-long-division-with-connected-parent).