# How to manually write polynomials long division rather than using the automated polynom?

Tags: pdftex, polynom, polynomials

I very new to LaTeX and currently try to practice writing engineering reports with it as a replacement for Microsoft Word. In one of my assignments I have to do Polynomial Long Divisions. I found through some research the `\usepackage{polynom}` package but this just does the polynomial for you like this one:

```
$\polylongdiv{x^3+3x^2+4}{(x-2)}$
```

Is there not a way to manually enter your own results even though they will be the same because this feels like cheating to me.

Thank you very much

Comment: maybe the answer to this question could be helpful:  [Multivariate polynomial long division using LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50404/579).  it offers approaches other than using `polynom`.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153295/long-division-of-polynomials-in-lyx/153413?s=1|1.4416#153413