# Multivariate polynomial long division in LaTex

Tags: math-mode, packages, typography, arrays, polynom

How do I typeset polynomial long division with multiple variables using LaTeX? I want to do polynomial long division with two and more divisors. I know there was a similar question already answered here, but the answer couldn't help since I want the long division to look like that:
[image]

I could already solve it for when having only one divisor, but when having two it doesn't look good anymore. 
Can somebody help me fixing that?

This is the code I currently have:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bbm}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{pgfplots}  
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %deutsche Umlaute
\input longdiv.tex
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}

\newcommand\Mydiv[2]{%
\strut#1$\kern.25em\smash{\raise.3ex\hbox{$\big)$}}$\mkern-8mu
        \overline{\enspace\strut#2}}

$$
\begin{array}{rll}
    q_1: x \phantom{000000000} \\[-3pt]
    q_2: -1 \phantom{00000000} \\[-3pt]
    \Mydiv{\begin{array}{r}
xy-1\\
x+y
\end{array}}{x^2y-2x-y+4} \\[-3pt]  
      \underline{x^2y- \phantom{0} x \phantom{000000}} \\
      4 \\[-3pt]

  \end{array}
$$
```

This gives me this result:
[image]
I don't like the way the two divisors are taller than the bracet, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it...
Thank you very much already!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It is good that you have provided a code example, but it would be helpful when you make the example compilable, i.e., when somebody copy-pastes the code to a new file on their own machine and runs LaTeX on it it should result in the output that you show (currently it shows an error: `! LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.`). Also, when you include an image of the output (which is helpful), then a real screenshot might be easier to read than a photo.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Multivariate polynomial long division using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50404/579).

Comment: Arrays are normally centered relative to each other.  Try using [t].