# How to add phantom space in math mode without losing "natural" spacing?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I want to align contents of my equations inside an already aligned environment like `align`:

[image: Good alignment using the mathcolor command]

Below is what I get using the `\phantom` command as a trick to get the previous spacing together with a minimal working example:

[image: Bad alignment using the phantom command]

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  N &= (-9) - (+5) &
  O &= (+7) - (-8) &
  P &= (+5) + (-6) &
  Q &= (-3) + (+2) \\
  %
  &=\phantom{(} -9 \phantom{)-(} -5 &
  &=\phantom{(+} 7 \phantom{)-(} +8 &
  &=\phantom{(+} 5 \phantom{)+(} -6 &
  &=\phantom{(} -3 \phantom{)+(} +2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

It seems like I'm encountering a similar problem as in [question 28075 (Phantom width of binary operator)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28075/19042). Reading [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38984/19042) to question 38984, I have the feeling I'm losing the character's class and hence loosing the "natural" spacing.

Is there a proper way to add phantom space in math mode?

Comment: Wrapping the phantoms in `\mathopen` might help (untested)

Comment: As a workaround for now, I use the `\mathcolor` command defined in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85035/19042) to question 85035 to display white text...

Comment: @daleif it works perfectly ! Does it force the caracter to be of class 4 ?

Comment: It leaves the stream in a state where an opening char has just been passed

Comment: @remjg: Would you consider this alternative another possibility or perhaps an answer? [code](http://pastebin.com/EimfYeMz) / [output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PDULc.png)

Comment: May be related: [\phantom with always correct spacing (taking into account its surroundings) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168004/phantom-with-always-correct-spacing-taking-into-account-its-surroundings/168008#168008), [align - Aligning a broken equation using phantom - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590181/aligning-a-broken-equation-using-phantom)

Answer (score 12):

Easy fix: Just surround the unary minus and plus signs in curly brackets `{` `}`:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  N &= (-9) - (+5) &
  O &= (+7) - (-8) &
  P &= (+5) + (-6) &
  Q &= (-3) + (+2) \\
  %
  &=\hphantom{(} {-}9 \hphantom{)-(} {-}5 &
  &=\hphantom{(+} 7 \hphantom{)-(} {+}8 &
  &=\hphantom{(+} 5 \hphantom{)+(} {-}6 &
  &=\hphantom{(} {-}3 \hphantom{)+(} {+}2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The rules for binary atoms are a little special to distinguish a binary minus (`a + b`) from a unary minus (`-1`). In the binary case, there is additional space around the operator, which is missing in the latter case.

TeX allows to stay a binary operator, if it is surrounded by compatible context: `a + b`, `4 + \int`, ... Other atoms like an open parentheses on the left prevents the binary spacing: `(-9)` is set without additional spaces. However, the property of the open parentheses does not go outside the `\phantom`. In this case TeX considers the whole subformula `\phantom{(}` as acceptable partner for a binary minus and the spacing increases.

`\mathord{-}` or the shorter `{-}` forces TeX to set a unary minus. The latter works, because standalone curly braces in math mode make a subformula, whose acts as `\mathord`.

Answer (score 6):

An aligned TABstack:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackaligngap{0pt}
\begin{document}
\[
%\TABunaryLeft% IS ALREADY THE DEFAULT
\alignstackanchor[8pt]{
  N =& (&-9&) - (&+5&) &\quad
  O =& (&+7&) - (&-8&) &\quad
  P =& (&+5&) + (&-6&) &\quad
  Q =& (&-3&) + (&+2&) 
  }{
    =& & -9&  &-5 &&
    =& &  7&  &+8 &&
    =& &  5&  &-6 &&
    =& & -3&  & +2&
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can get away with phantoms, declaring the right type, such as `\mathopen{\hphantom{(}}` or `\mathbin{\hphantom{+}}`, but perhaps a more customizable version is better.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\newcolumntype{E}{
  r % left-hand side
  >{{}}c<{{}} % equals
  c % open parenthesis
  r % number
  c % closed parenthesis
  >{{}}c<{{}} % operator
  c % open parenthesis
  r % number
  c % closed parenthesis
}
\newcolumntype{?}{@{\hspace{.5em}}|@{\hspace{.5em}}}
\begin{array}{E ? E ? E ? E}
  N &= &(& -9 &)& - &(& +5 &)&
  O &= &(& +7 &)& - &(& -8 &)&
  P &= &(& +5 &)& + &(& -6 &)&
  Q &= &(& -3 &)& + &(& +2 &) \\
  %
    &= & & -9 & &   & & -5 & &
    &= & &  7 & &   & & +8 & &
    &= & &  5 & &   & & -6 & &
    &= & & -3 & &   & & +2 &
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

You can redefine the column type `?` if you don't want rules which, in this case, may be better in order to clearly separate the various expressions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You  can do that with `alignedat` and no `\phantom`:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  N &=\!\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}%
  ( -& 9 &) - (+ &5)\\
  - & 9 & {} - {} & 5 & %
  \end{alignedat}
  &
  O &=\!\begin{alignedat}[t] {2}%
  ( + &7 &) - (-& 8)\\
  & 7 & {}+{} & 8%
  \end{alignedat}
  & P &=\!\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}%
  ( + &5 &) + (- &6)\\
  & 5 &{} -{}&6%
  \end{alignedat}
  & Q &=\!\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}%
  ( -&3 &) + ( +& 2)\\
  - &3 & {}+{} & 2%
  \end{alignedat}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you're getting binary, rather than unary, pluses and minuses in the second line.  wrap them in braces to make them "ordinary" characters.

Comment: @barbara beeton: I had to fiddle with this problem to obtain it! In my opinion, semantically, they have to be binary.

Comment: that's a reasonable explanation.  i withdraw my suggestion (but leave the comment since someone else may have the same reaction).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `\phantom{+}`, which is (roughly speaking) interpreted as `\phantom{{+}}`, i.e., not a relation, use

```
\mathrel{\phantom{+}}
```

which forces `\phantom{+}` to be treated as a relation.