# Aligning a broken equation using phantom

Tags: equations, align, phantom

I am trying to break an equation and align the characters under each other. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
f(a) &= f(b) + 3 + \\
&\phantom{{}=f(b) + } 4 \nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

This aligns `4` under the plus sign, however, I want `4` to be aligned under `3`. Do I need to add a character to the `phantom`?

---

The code produces

[image]

Comment: Try `{} =` inside the phantom

Comment: @daleif Thanks - `4` is still not 100% under `3` though.

Comment: Please provide an image a show exactly the code being used

Comment: @daleif Please see the updated OP

Comment: Right the `=` neeeds to see something aster it as well (like in the image the spacing after `3` is wrong `\phantom{{}=f(b) + {}} `

Comment: @daleif Nice, thanks! Gimme an answer that I can accept :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing phantoms one often have to remember to have relations and binaries have something to work on, as in `+1` and `{}+1` does not have the same spacing.

Here we need a `{}` before the `=` and after the `+`:

```
\phantom{{}=f(b) + {}}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would not use `\phantom` but rather move anchor `&` before "3" and "4":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f(a) = f(b) + {} & 3  + {} \\
                 & 4  \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]